# List Index Out of Range? for Scores

Tags: python, while-loop, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm trying to loop through a list of teams that I attained from Patriots.com scores by using Python and BeautifulSoup. I use scrape and a loop to get the scores, teams, and Weeks for every year between 2001 and 2018. After 2001, the I get a list index out of range error

I tried changing multiple things like the integer I use or if the len() of the list needs int()

```
m = 0
    while m < int(len(the_teams)):
      m = m+1
      q = the_scores[m].split('-')
      val = []
      for y in q:
        int_val = int(y)
        val.append(int_val)
      if val[0] > val[1]:
        print("The Patriots won against the " + the_teams[m] + " during " 
+ the_game[m] + " with a score of " + the_scores[m] + "!")
      else:
        print("The Patriots lost against the " + the_teams[m] + " during 
" +the_game[m] + " with a score of " + the_scores[m] + ".")
```

I expect to output every game and their score in the 2 formats in the print statements at the end

Comment: please give us your input data so that we can help to debug it.  On your own, add a lot of print() in your code to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You’re incrementing your index *before* you’re doing your analysis, after checking if it’s a valid index.

If you move `m = m+ 1` - or the more pythonic `m += 1` - to the bottom of the while loop, rather than the top, it should work as expected.